# I wan to nest two sql command. The first one t relies on the result from a previous query

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

**I am able to read from both tables individual

For the first Query, I run
'SELECT DISTINCT  `group_id` FROM `wp_um_groups_members` '

And Get

```
Group ID
64
179
430
```

And When I select One Group And Run The Second Query

```
SELECT COUNT( `user_id1` ) AS Member
FROM `wp_um_groups_members`
WHERE `group_id` = 179 AND
    status = 'approved' AND
    `user_id1` IN ( SELECT ID FROM `wp_users` WHERE ID = `user_id1` )
```

I get The Below

```
Members
9
```

I am trying to use the results of the table as inputs to the first query to arrive as the below-desired result

**

```
Group ID Member 
64          0
179         9
430         3
```

[image: Table I am trying to Query]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `left join` and aggregation:

```
SELECT ugm.group_id, 
       SUM(ugm.status = 'approved' AND ugm.id IS NOT NULL) AS num_members
FROM `wp_um_groups_members` ugm LEFT JOIN
     wp_users u
     ON ugm.user_id1 = u.id
GROUP BY ugm.group_id;
```

This uses MySQL syntax, but can easily be converted to a `case` or `filter` if you are using a different database.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I knew the command was LEFT JOIN but I don't use SQL as much

Comment: The 'ugm' name you used above can you please explain what that means.

Comment: @kolawole . . . That is a *table alias*.  It is an important part of the SQL language.  The query also qualifies all column references, which is a best practice.